# Resource bundles in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, resources, ios, bundle

How do I create a resource bundle to use in an iPhone/iPad app? Is it simply a folder with the `.bundle` extension or do I have to do something else to make it work?

Are there any special considerations for Universal apps (ie: do I have to create separate bundles for each platform?) and localized resources?

I would like to create and use a resource bundle similar to the one that [Facebook Connect iPhone SDK](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/) has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File Menu => New => New File... => Resources = Settings bundle...

Name it anything you want, for example "MyBundle".

From Finder, open contents and drag any folder of images or whatever.

Access by...

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBundle.bundle/images/logout.png"];
```

Comment: Feels kinda hacky, especially the imageNamed: part with whatevername.bundle.